Where is the water in our sump pail coming from?
We bought our house 2 years ago. When we purchased it there was a dry sump pump pit in the basement (no actual sump pump). Fast forward 2 years and our sump pump pit overflowed and slightly and flooded our basement.
Since then, we have had a sump pump installed.  For about 4 weeks our sump pump has been pumping consistently about every 5 minutes.  Where can all this water be coming from?  A few things to consider...

The person we purchased this house from never had a sump pump and never had any flooding issues (allegedly).

Our neighbor's sump pump only runs when it rains and our neighbors 2 doors down don't have a sump pump in their basement and haven't had any issues. So this excessive water seems to only be affecting us.

We had the city come out to test it and confirm that it is ground water vs city water, and it is groundwater.


What are the next steps?  Could it be an aquifer? Is there anything to do to lessen the amount of groundwater? or try and find the source?

Any heavy construction near?  Has rain fall amounts changed?  Are downspouts drained away and there is a grade away from the house?

yes, there is heavy construction, there is a school being remodeled up the street.  Also a ton of houses being flipped in the neighborhood. Additionally our neighbor across the street had a house fire and have not lived there for 6 months.  Not sure if that has anything to do with it.  But if it was heavy construction, isn't it a little weird that it is only affecting our home?

Soil types can control the flow of water, so it's entirely possible that a change in water usage near you could only affect you and not others.

is there anything to be done about it? or is it just figuring out how to maintain it, until it hopefully changes again?

I don't understand the question. That's normal behavior where I live, during the snowmelt season and after rainy periods. I have two sprinklers in my front yard right now doing exactly that.  Some neighbors have none. Some have water year round. Why do you think it's abnormal that there is variation?

@isherwood  I live in Colorado, we do not have a ton of a rain. It has been 80 degrees the last 3 weeks. I am talking about the sump pump consistently pumping daily, gallons and gallons of water.  Seems a little excessive for rain or snow melt.  Your sump pump runs constantly (every 5 minutes) for weeks on end?

That is correct. Granted, I'm in Minnesota and we have had quite a bit of rain this year (thank goodness).

The bottom line is that the internet isn't the place to find out where your water comes from. Either do some local inquiry and investigation or hire someone. We can only throw darts from here.

of course.  we have people helping, just trouble shooting on the internet.

Colorado? Pretty dry state - so pump it into a tanker and sell it ;^)

Has your water bill changed at all in the past 4 weeks?

@Huesmann, no.  Water Bill hasn't changed, City came and tested the water to know it was ground water and they checked our meter and our usage is the same.
